# Complex association topic in Rails / mongoid with inverse foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, mongoid

Having a problem getting associations right. In my model I have users and requests. A request has an owner and many participants. A user has many requests and many participations.

I tried to model it like this:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :requests, inverse_of: :owner
  has_many :participations, class_name: 'Request', inverse_of: :participants
  ...

class Request
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :requests
  has_many :participants, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :participations
  ...
```

When I try to set a participation by calling

```
 @request.participants << current_user
```

I get the following error:

> message: When adding a(n) User to Request#participants, Mongoid could
>   not determine the inverse foreign key to set. The attempted key was
>   'participations_id'. summary: When adding a document to a relation,
>   Mongoid attempts to link the newly added document to the base of the
>   relation in memory, as well as set the foreign key to link them on the
>   database side. In this case Mongoid could not determine what the
>   inverse foreign key was. resolution: If an inverse is not required,
>   like a belongs_to or has_and_belongs_to_many, ensure that :inverse_of
>   => nil is set on the relation. If the inverse is needed, most likely the inverse cannot be figured out from the names of the relations and
>   you will need to explicitly tell Mongoid on the relation what the
>   inverse is. Example:   class Lush     include Mongoid::Document
>   has_one :whiskey, class_name: "Drink", inverse_of: :alcoholic   end
>   class Drink     include Mongoid::Document     belongs_to :alcoholic,
>   class_name: "Lush", inverse_of: :whiskey   end

I don't get it, I have all inverse_of set, what am I doing wrong?